# Overloading comparison operators for a MyString class

Tags: c++

```
bool operator == (const MyString& left, const MyString& right)
{
    if(left.value == right.value)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
bool operator != (const MyString& left, const MyString& right)
{
    if(left == right)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
bool operator < (const MyString& left, const MyString& right)
{
    if(strcmp(left.value, right.value) == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool operator > (const MyString& left, const MyString& right)
{
    if(strcmp(left.value, right.value) == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool operator <= (const MyString& left, const MyString& right)
{
    if(strcmp(left.value, right.value) == -1 || strcmp(left.value, right.value) == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool operator >= (const MyString& left, const MyString& right)
{
    if(strcmp(left.value, right.value) == 1 || strcmp(left.value, right.value) == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

These are my implemented comparison operators for my MyString class, but they fail the test program that my professor gave me and could use some direction. What is the problem?

Comment: The `strcmp` function can return zero, _negative_, or _positive_. It doesn't _have_ to be `-1` or `1`.

Comment: Good answers, but I don't think `operator==` is doing what you want. You're comparing pointers, not values. Try this: `return !strcmp(left.value, right.value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express each comparator with just two of them:

```
bool operator == (const MyString& left, const MyString& right) {
    return strcmp(left.value, right.value) == 0;
}
bool operator < (const MyString& left, const MyString& right) {
    return strcmp(left.value, right.value) < 0;
}

bool operator != (const MyString& left, const MyString& right) {
    return !(left == right);
}
bool operator > (const MyString& left, const MyString& right) {
    return !(left == right) && !(left < right);
}
bool operator <= (const MyString& left, const MyString& right) {
    return left < right || left == right;
}
bool operator >= (const MyString& left, const MyString& right) {
    return !(left < right);
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to use this solution because it avoids code replication.

Comment: I did use this, and it worked great. Plus it's very clean and looks good. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with the strcmp. You can see the documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/).

You can further reduce the code to something like:

```
bool operator < (const MyString& left, const MyString& right) 
{ 
    return (strcmp(left.value, right.value) < 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think strcmp supposed to return a non-zero value for inequality cases. So instead of using 1 and -1, you may want to try greater than 0 and less than 0 cases.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you only implement `operator==` and `operator<`. All the other relational operators can be delegated to them, ensuring code re-use. There's even a CRTP mixin in Boost which can do this for you, I believe.

Comment: simply including `utility` will also get you the other operators: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp